# Error when using @Before("args(name)")

Tags: spring

I am writing a simple AspectJ application with Spring.My Spring Version is 4.1.4. When I run my code, I get this Run-Time error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.mehrdad.Aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
```

My Aspect Class is  as below:

```
package org.mehrdad.Aspect;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.mehrdad.model.Circle;


@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {


    @Before("allCircleMethods()")
    public void LoggingAdvice(JoinPoint jp)
    {


    }


    @Before("args(name)")
    public void stringArgumentMethods(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Name " + name);
    }



    @Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
    public void allGetters(){}

    @Pointcut("within(org.mehrdad.model.Circle)")
    public void allCircleMethods(){}
}
```

and main function is :

```
package org.mehrdad.AOPSpring;

import org.mehrdad.Service.ShapeService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class AopMain {



        public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
                ShapeService shapeService = context.getBean("shapeservice", ShapeService.class);
                shapeService.getCircle().setName("AHAHAHA");
                System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
            }

        }
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it :

```
@Before(argNames="name")
```

Comment: @vincent -- this post has been flagged for review as low quality. StackOverflow discourages code only answers. We prefer to have a full explanation containing an explanation of where the OP went wrong, and why the solution you're offering fixes it. Please read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

If you use @After("args(name)") it will work because the value of name won't be set until the function is called.